# PyGame Circular Collision Issues - Circle Interior

Tags: python, collision-detection, physics, pygame, game-physics

I'm making a puzzle game that requires the user to 'draw' circles onto a background to get a ball to the exit. They create circles by holding their mouse button, the circle grows; when it is big enough, they let go and it is 'punched' into the physical space and balls then react to it.

I have a problem, however, that when two circles are intersecting (so a ball *should* pass through), if the intersection is not larger than the diameter of the ball the ball collides with the interior of the circle as usual.

This may be a little hard to comprehend, so here's a link to the screencast showing the problem (You can't embed videos on Stack Overflow): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dKyPzqTDhs

Hopefully that made my problem clear. Here is the Python / PyGame code for the `Ball` and `Circle` classes:

```
class Ball():
    def __init__(self, (x,y), size, colourID):
        """Setting up the new instance"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.exited = False
        self.colour = setColour(colourID)
        self.thickness = 0
        self.speed = 0.01
        self.angle = math.pi/2

    def display(self, surface):
        """Draw the ball"""
        # pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen,cx,cy,new_dist,settings['MINIMAP_RINGS'])
        if self.exited != True:
            pygame.draw.circle(surface, self.colour, (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.size, self.thickness)

    def move(self):
        """Move the ball according to angle and speed"""
        self.x += math.sin(self.angle) * self.speed
        self.y -= math.cos(self.angle) * self.speed
        (self.angle, self.speed) = module_physicsEngine.addVectors((self.angle, self.speed), gravity)
        self.speed *= drag
```

And the `Circle` class:

```
class Circle():
    def __init__(self, (x,y), size, colourID):
        """Set up the new instance of the Circle class"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.colour = setColour(colourID)
        self.thickness = 2
        self.angle = 0 # Needed for collision...
        self.speed = 0 # detection against balls

    def display(self, surface):
        """Draw the circle"""
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, self.colour, (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.size, self.thickness)
```

Within the main loop of the game (`while running == True:` etc.), this code is used to perform actions on each ball:

```
for b in balls:
    b.move()
    for i, ball in enumerate(balls):
        for ball2 in balls[i+1:]:
            collideBalls(ball, ball2)
        collideCircle(b) #      <---------------- This is the important line
        collideExit(b)
        b.display(screen)
```

And finally, the `collideCircle(b)` function, which is called once per ball to check for collisions with the interior of a circle, and also to check if the circles are intersecting.

```
def collideCircle(ball):
    """Check for collision between a ball and a circle"""

    hit = False
    closestDist = 0

    for c in circles:
        # Code cannot be replaced with physicsEngine.collideTest because it
        # is slightly differnt, testing if ball [ball] inside a circle [c]
        dx = c.x - ball.x
        dy = c.y - ball.y
        distance = math.hypot(dx, dy)

        if distance <= c.size - ball.size:
            # If BALL inside any CIRCLE
            hit = False
            break
        else:
            # If we're outside of a circle.
            if closestDist < c.size - (distance - ball.size):
                hit = c
                closestDist = (c.size - (distance - ball.size))

    if hit:

        module_physicsEngine.circleBounce(hit, ball)
```

Ok, so I know that this has been a bit of a long and talky question, but I think you have all the information needed. Is the solution to make the balls interact correctly something to do with the line `if distance <= c.size - ball.size:`?

Anyway, thanks in advance!

Nathan out.

**TL;DR - Watch the youtube video, and let me know why it's not working.**

Comment: Looks like a great concept for a game. I think Yann is right that the problem is you're calling circleBounce in circumstances when you shouldn't, namely when the ball is intersecting two or more circles). Looks like quite a complex problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with unintended hits rather than missed ones. What you really want to check is if all parts of the ball are covered by some circle, while the check you're doing is if any circle only partially overlaps - but an override if any circle fully covers the ball.

I figure for any potential hit point, i.e. closest inner wall of a circle, let that point "walk" along the wall by checking its distance from all other circles. Should it then leave the ball, it was a false hit.

First you find the list of circles that touch the ball at all. As before, if any of them cover it, you can skip the rest of the checks. Also find the closest wall point to the ball for the circles. For each of those closest wall points, if it overlaps another circle, move it to the intersection point which is closest to the ball but further away than the current point. Discard it if it's outside the ball. Repeat the procedure for all circles, since more than two may overlap. Also note that the moving of the point may cause it to enter new circles.

You could precompute the intersection points and discard any that are a ball radius inside of any other circle.

This can surely be improved on, but it's a start, I think. I suspect a bug involving the case when both intersection points of a pair of circles overlap the ball, but a walk chain leads one of them outside the ball. Perhaps the initial collision points should be replaced only by both intersection points, not the closest.

Comment: I'm in the process of testing this solution, so here's hoping it works. I'll mark this as correct tonight, hopefully.

Comment: Ah, sorry Yann! Sorry! Here you go, it worked. It still needed a faily comprehensive re-write of my code to get everything working, but yes. XD

Answer (score 0):

I watched the video and I like the game principle. :)

Maybe the problem is that you `break` out of the loop as soon as you encounter a circle that encloses the ball. I'm referring to the snippet

```
if distance <= c.size - ball.size:
    # If BALL inside any CIRCLE
    hit = False
    break
```

Why would you not check all of the other circles, in that case? There might be another circle yet unchecked that causes a `hit`.

Btw, I wouldn't say `if condition == True:`, that's unpythonic. Just say `if condition:`.

Comment: That `break` is the override that allows the ball to pass between circles at all (while any circle fully covers it).